# Cannot open OR create MVC3 project or solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

this is driving me crazy, I`ve been unable to find a solution on SO or anywhere else.

```
VS2010 Professional SP1
MVC3 installed
NUGET updated
Windows 7 Professional
```

Any MVC3 project fails to load with the

> The project type is not supported by this installation.

message.

What's crazy is I cannot even create a new MVC3 project, even though the template is available! VS gets through the new project wizard project, then I get the same failure message:

> project type not supported

I've reinstalled VS and MVC3.